# Is it possible to run Gnome 3 without 3D acceleration hardware?

Tags: 11.04, hardware, gnome

If I don't have a hardware that supports 3D acceleration, is it possible to run Gnome 3? If no, is there some work on it and where I can go to get tunned about the progress of it?

Just one extra doubt: I run Unity 3D not Unity 2D, but my hardware doesn't support 3D acceleration, is it possible? If no, maybe my hardware supports it, but I just don't know and if it's true, why I can't set Gnome 3 to run?

[Added]  `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` returns:

```
OpenGL vendor string:   Tungsten Graphics, Inc
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) 915GM GEM 20100330 DEVELOPMENT x86/MMX/SSE2
OpenGL version string:  1.4 Mesa 7.10.2

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity supported:          yes
```

So, yes my hardware seems to support 3D hardware acceleration (OMG! This dinosaur has it's tricks! I just can't believe), well I always stay happy with sooo many YESes and no errors =D Glad! Resuming, I really want to use Gnome 3, not Gnome-shell or fallback, so, what is missing? Maybe my 480Mb RAM Memory? Or my Celeron M at 1.6GHz???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNOME 3 has GNOME Shell (requires 3D acceleration) and GNOME Fallback (does not require 3D acceleration, it's similar to the traditional GNOME 2 Panel).

There are no plans to make GNOME Shell to work without 3D acceleration, so sadly you are out of luck.

Reading your question, I think it would help if you can run

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

which will show whether your driver for the graphic card is capable for 3D acceleration. Post the results in your initial question.

Comment: I'm spinning of confusion, I can easily run gnome-shell here, that gnome-shell that was available before Gnome 3, but if I try to install Gnome 3 here it just breaks the interface and the system fall in the black(or purple) terminal screen(yes, I already tried again, two more times), if I try running Fedora, it even starts up the Live CD interface.

Comment: GNOME Shell uses `mutter` and Unity uses `compiz` for their 3D effects (compositing window manager). So, there might be some driver issues between the two. Also, the GNOME Shell you get from the Ubuntu repositories is incompatible with Unity, so it's better to stick with Unity for now. Ubuntu 11.10 will have GNOME 3 which should make it easier to switch to GNOME Shell.